# Cifs mount hanging

Tags: linux, cifs, hanging

I have a problem with a mount between a windows server and a linux machine.
The share is on the windows machine.
From time to time, the windows machine goes nuts and some services fail on it. After a few seconds everything is back to normal.
The problem is that after this fail, i can`t list the mounted share anymore. df / ls hangs.
After a few atempts i get to unmount the share using the lazy option.

Here is my problem. I can ping the windows machine from the linux machine, i can mount shares from the windows machine from other machines, but when i try to mount it again from linux it hangs. I did a verbose mount and this is what i get:

```
domain=dom
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=xx.xx.xx.xx,unc=\\servername\sharename,credentials=/etc/cifscredentials,nosetuids,ver=1,user=domainuser,domain=dom,pass=********
```

It remains like this until i hit Ctrl+C.
I get nothing in /var/log/messages, or anywhere else.

Can anyone give me any advice ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting from the networking configuration. If you are on wireless network the dropouts like this could be just plain interference from neighboring Wi-Fi on the same channel. I would also try another even older router and direct wired connection, if possible.

Also make sure neither Linux nor Windows box goes to sleep while share is mounted.